# SQL - Giving AS keyword in UPDATE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
update MESSAGES set status=
    (select (CASE 
               WHEN from_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                      WHEN status='A' 
                      THEN 'S' 
                  WHEN status='R' 
                      THEN 'D' 
                     END)
               WHEN to_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                       WHEN status='A' 
                       THEN 'R' 
                   WHEN status='S' 
                       THEN 'D' 
                     END) 
             END)
    as status_value)
where primary_key='236499681204' 
and status_value not null ;
```

The problem with this query is, at the last line, `status_value` is not recognized. If I remove the last comparison, `and status_value not null`, it works. I dint expect the above version to work, but could someone tell me an alternative that would achieve the same?

Is there a way I can use the `AS` keyword in the `UPDATE` query to define the variable `status_value`?

**Edit**

The actual requirement is not just that i check if `status_value` is `null`, but also that I *dont* perform any update if it is `null`

Comment: AS is used to establish an alias for a column when in the result set.  UPDATE has no result set, so AS in this context is meaningless.  Perhaps you can describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I need to set the value of `status` to `status_value` only if it is not null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `ELSE STATUS` and remove `and status_value not null`:

```
  update MESSAGES set status=
    (select (CASE 
               WHEN from_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                      WHEN status='A' 
                      THEN 'S' 
                  WHEN status='R' 
                      THEN 'D' 
                     END)
               WHEN to_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                       WHEN status='A' 
                       THEN 'R' 
                   WHEN status='S' 
                       THEN 'D' 
                     END) 
             ELSE STATUS 
             END)
    as status_value)
where primary_key='236499681204';
```

You can also try to use `view`

```
create view MyView as
select (CASE 
               WHEN from_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                      WHEN status='A' 
                      THEN 'S' 
                  WHEN status='R' 
                      THEN 'D' 
                     END)
               WHEN to_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                       WHEN status='A' 
                       THEN 'R' 
                   WHEN status='S' 
                       THEN 'D' 
                     END) 
             END)
    as status_value;

update MESSAGES set status= mv.status_value
from MyView mv
where primary_key='236499681204'
and mv.status_value is null
```

or you can use `case in condition`

```
 update MESSAGES set status=
    (select (CASE 
               WHEN from_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                      WHEN status='A' 
                      THEN 'S' 
                  WHEN status='R' 
                      THEN 'D' 
                     END)
               WHEN to_id='111111111' 
               THEN (CASE 
                       WHEN status='A' 
                       THEN 'R' 
                   WHEN status='S' 
                       THEN 'D' 
                     END) 
             END)
    as status_value)
where primary_key='236499681204'
and CASE
     WHEN from_id='111111111' 
      THEN (CASE 
             WHEN status='A' 
             THEN 'S' 
             WHEN status='R' 
             THEN 'D' 
            END)
     WHEN to_id='111111111' 
      THEN (CASE 
             WHEN status='A' 
             THEN 'R' 
             WHEN status='S' 
             THEN 'D' 
            END) 
    END is not null;
```

Comment: The actual requirement is not just that i check if `status_value` is `null`, but also that I *dont* perform any update if it is `null`

Comment: If select will return null, they will set to status a status (status=status), so it is the same.

Comment: No, it isn't, because I'm counting the Number of Rows effected to make out the result. If zero rows have been edited, I throw an error

Comment: I edited the post, maybe views will help you. What is your DBMS?

Comment: is there any way I can get this query into one single statement?

Comment: Maybe, but we have to know your DBMS, because some solutions don't work on every DBMS.

Comment: I am afraid that not, because you can't use an alias in where. View is more readable.

Comment: I'm using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. So wont I have to break hte view query down into a single statement?

Comment: I don't use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: well, is there a way I can get your query (the one that uses the `View`) to one single statement? Coz that would be good enough for me

Comment: No, you have to create view on DB, then you can use it in update.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to do a sub-query for the update statement, when I don't think it's really all that necessary.

You can simplify the query a bit like this:

```
UPDATE MESSAGES
SET status = CASE
         WHEN 
            (from_id='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'S'
         WHEN 
            (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'R'
         WHEN 
            (from_id  ='111111111' AND status='R') OR
            (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='S') THEN 'D'

         ELSE status
         END
WHERE priamry_key = '236499681204'
```

Comment: your conditions are a little messed up, but the idea is clear. thanks for the answer :)

Comment: The actual requirement is not just that i check if `status_value` is `null`, but also that I *dont* perform any update if it is `null`

Comment: But `status_value` is something you're making up, using the `CASE` statement. I changed the query to just leave the status at its current value if it doesn't match any of the conditions defined (which would be the same as what you want, I think)

Comment: No, it isn't, because I'm counting the Number of Rows effected to make out the result. If zero rows have been edited, I throw an error. If I use your code, I'll never know if there has been a change or not

Answer (score 1):

assuming all you want is to get rid of the null, you can do this:

```
update MESSAGES set status=
    IFNULL(
    (CASE WHEN from_id='111111111' THEN 
        (CASE WHEN status='A' THEN 'S' 
        WHEN status='R' THEN 'D' END)
    WHEN to_id='111111111' THEN 
        (CASE WHEN status='A' THEN 'R' 
        WHEN status='S' THEN 'D' END) END),
    status)
where primary_key='236499681204' ;
```

Comment: The actual requirement is not just that i check if `status_value` is `null`, but also that I *dont* perform any update if it is `null`